# Which AR (Augmented Reality) framework (Android & iOS) is suitable for my situation

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

**My Situation**

I want to build an Application that can recognize an Image to produce a corresponding model.

i.e. I focus the camera to show a printed image on the card that is designed by myself ( apple logo ) , then it will show a 3D model(.md2) on the screen which is also designed by myself.

I have googled many framework that worked on both Android & iOS, but the documentations are very limited and the trial version does not support me to test it.

for example, 
http://www.metaio.com/sdk/

But their demo is not comprehensive enough to suite my situation

**My Question**

1.Would anyone can share their experience of developing with AR framework (not the AR core) on Android & iOS?

2.Is there any framework that support me to add a image as a key then it will map to my model with just a couples line of codes?

3.if Q2 is not possible, is there any approaches of some framework can also archive the some goal but more complex ?

```
//Logic flow

String key = "APPLE";
sdk.putKeyImage(key,apple.png);

   ... 

if (sdk.identifiedAs(key)){

    //Do something

    //Example
    sdk.showApple3DModel();
    play(showSnakeEatApple.mp4);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an android app developer. So according to my experince for android, you can go for

1. Vuforia (https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android)
2. Wikitude (http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/android)

These above 2 are enough good to implement AR app in android.

Vuforia is having well documented, also they have more libraries & mainly those are free. & Wikitude is best for making apps faster. I recommend you to use any of these for your AR app development in android.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should compare several AR frameworks to find a proper solution for your problem. Many different AR tools come to my mind. For example, Vuforia, LayAR, Kudan AR. To take a deeper look at the variety of possible options read the comprehensive comparison of the most popular frameworks: http://cases.azoft.com/top-5-tools-creating-augmented-reality-apps/

Answer (score 1):

yes i did work on it not much but little bit i did research on augmented reality and after research i found one open source and cross platform well known sdk its name is

VUFORIA SDK
there are various SDK you find on google but trust me VUFORIA is best and flexible who gives lots of option

for that you need to install NDK in eclipse cause it  have core cpp code who compile by NDK in eclipse

[video tutorial click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0_3s63c5dE)

[sdk and documentation click here](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/tutorials)

[steps click here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/step-step-unity-tutorial)

hope it will be helpful for you thank you happy coding

Comment: Just to note that the Vuforia SDK is not open source.